# Is it possible to get Cartel Coins from any other source?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Various items can be purchased in-game using Cartel Coins from the in-game Black Market.

I have noticed that it is possible to get certain items marked as 'Cartel Items' (for example a minor experience boost consumable item) but is it possible to get Cartel Coins from any source other than the 'pay to win' store?

Comment: You don't get Cartel Coins from the Cartel Market ... other than grants for buying the game/subscribing/referring friends/security key/etc. ([website](http://www.swtor.com/free)) you only get them via buying them from [http://www.swtor.com/buy](http://www.swtor.com/buy) and potentially via retail cards in the future (similar to gametime cards).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes!  In Game Update 2.0, certain Legacy Achievements grant Cartel Coins.  They only grant once per Legacy, so it's not a feasible way to get a lot of them for free, but it's kind of cool.

From [the official SWTOR blog](http://www.swtor.com/info/news/blog/20130409) (emphasis mine):

> This update also includes an all-new Achievements system. Starting in Game Update 2.0, players will be able to earn Achievements for all sorts of activities in-game, including crafting, exploring and unleashing their wrath on the world around them. Over 1,900 Achievements are in this release, and we see the system as a great way to add more, and more varied gameplay in future updates. **Achievements can also grant rewards such as titles and in some cases Cartel Coins.**

Currently you can get a total of 860, as per [Dulfy](http://dulfy.net/2013/02/21/swtor-legacy-achievements-guide/).

Comment: So about $8 worth.

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge, No. However, most (all?) items and upgrades purchasable with Cartel Coins are themselves tradable and can be resold using in game currency, such as via the GTN.

Comment: In fact, if any other site not officially and verifiably associated with SWTOR/Bioware offers to sell you cartel coins, I'd be very *very* suspicious...

Answer (score 3):

This may not have been the case at the time. But it appears bioware/EA have partnered with amazon as they sell cartel coin codes which come with a free gift (read : cosmetic/noncombat companion).

Source- [http://www.amazon.com/Star-Wars-The-Old-Republic/dp/B00DIIZ15A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DIIZ15A)

Answer (score -1):

You can get cartel coins without spending real money by completing achivements (880cc) using the official, free security key application of Bioware (gives a 6 digit code to use during logins, 100cc/month);
and by getting friends to subscribe using your referral link.

(For full list and details just google: "swtor free stuff" (1st hit))

These are not exploits, all of them are intended to be given to you,
all of them are in-game rewards, which you can earn (on any server, regardless if you are free to play, preferred, or subscriber)

Answer (score -2):

Cartel coins can be obtained by doing achievements. Each achievement that gives cartel coins give 20 of them. It is an easy way for f2p people to get them.

The easiest ones are the first planet class quest missions. You can get about 80 per day.

It works in a legacy system. There is 1 legacy per *server*, not per account.